# Deallocate pointer to a struct preserving memory addresses of nested variables

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, nested

```
template<typename T>
T& List<T>::popFront()
{
    if (head == NULL)
        throw std::underflow_error("List error: no head node available\n");
    if (tail == head)
        tail = NULL;
    T item = head->item;
    head = head->next;
    return item;
}
```

I have a recursive struct ListNode with the following fields:

```
template <typename T>
struct ListNode {
    T item;
    ListNode* next;
    ...
}
```

The problem is that I want to deallocate a head node after popFront procedure, but as all the nested nodes are indirectly pointing to the same address, their addresses also vanish from the heap. So for now as you can see above I just alter the pointer address of a head node to the next one, which I believe leads to a memory leak.

I do not exclude that I'm absolutely wrong with this approach and my assumption. Please, consider the most efficient way to perform such task, if this deallocation is really necessary.

Comment: You return a reference to a local, automatic variable. Using the returned reference has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user2079303 yes, didn't notice, fix that.

Comment: _" Please, consider the most efficient way to perform such task"_ The answer is to use the tried-and-tested Standard Library, so `std::list` or `std::forward_list`. Its authors know what they are doing and write efficient code.

Comment: @underscore_d obviously in a real project I'm going to use features from Standard Library, but for the seek of experience I try to implement some data structures by myself

Comment: @KirillKorolev when implementing data structures yourself just for the kicks, I recommend looking for the simplest correct way, rather than the most efficient way first. If you're lucky, they are the same way.

Comment: @KirillKorolev by the way, what is the point of having a tail pointer in a singly linked list? What is it used for?

Comment: @user2079303 to make procedures like pushBack(), topBack() work in a constant time, actually it is optional.

Comment: @KirillKorolev did you mean popBack? Tail does indeed get you constant time pushBack, but you cannot implement a constant time removal of last node.

Comment: @user2079303 No, I meant topBack (odd method) which corresponds to returning the last node's value without a deletion just by calling tail.item

Comment: @KirillKorolev I see. That is called `back` in the standard library. And if `front` is called `top`, then the complement would be `bottom` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

```
template<typename T>
T& List<T>::popFront()
{
    if (head == NULL)
        throw std::underflow_error("List error: no head node available\n");
    if (tail == head)
        tail = NULL;
    T item = head->item;
    head = head->next; //Memory leak, you just lost your only pointer to the head item
    return item; //Returning reference to stack variable, undefined behavior
}
```

I would suggest that you change the signature to return by value, so that you can return a local and deallocate the element in the heap.

```
template<typename T>
T List<T>::popFront()
{
    if (head == NULL)
        throw std::underflow_error("List error: no head node available\n");
    if (tail == head)
        tail = NULL;
    T item = head->item;
    ListNode* old_head = head; //keep this for deallocation
    head = head->next;
    delete old_head; //Deallocate the old head
    return item; //Return by value
}
```

You could, of course, adopt the behavior of [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and have different methods for access and popping, [`front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/front) and [`pop_front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) respectively.

As per the signature, `front()` returns a reference, which is far more efficient if `T` is a heavy object.

This is all assuming you're doing it for academic purposes, of course. Otherwise, well, use `std::list` or a similar standard library container.

Comment: thanks for your help, but as I said in a post, I used this approach, but head after deleting "old_head" is: 0x00cce9c0 {item=-572662307 next=0xdddddddd {item=??? next=??? } } which throws an exception. yes, only for the experience.

Comment: `head.next` looks like garbage value. Are you sure you initialize `next` to `NULL` on construction or at some point of the insertion to list? Are you sure that this garbage value does not happen immediately after `head = head->next;`? Did head for some reason point to itself meaning that deleting `old_head` actually deletes new `head`?

Comment: As patatahooligan said, check what `head->next` is pointing to when `popFront()` is called. Your problem is probably not in the `popFront()` function but somewhere else, that makes you have a bad structure.

Comment: @Ramon It seemed that a struct's deconstructor was an issue. I just realized that when I deallocate a node, I don't want to deallocate a next pointer. So I changed a deconstructor a bit and everything seemed to work properly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @KirillKorolev Yes, that's correct, the `ListNode` struct should not deallocate `next`, since you manage that in your `List` class. My pleasure, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When you pop the head, before deleting it, grab the next pointer and make it head.

```
template<typename T>
T List<T>::popFront()
{
    if (head == NULL)
        throw std::underflow_error("List error: no head node available");
    if (tail == head)
        tail = NULL;
    T item = head->item;
    ListNode *next = head->next;    // Grab next
    delete head;                    // Now it is safe to delete head
    head = next;                    // Head now points to next
    return item;
}
```

Is the tail needed here? Why not just have next of head equal to `NULL` when there is only one node?

EDIT: Just noticed. You're not supposed to return a reference to `Item` because we're destroying the `ListNode` that was holding it. Return by value. Alternatively you can return `ListNode*` rather than deleting it, but this is probably not how you want `List`'s interface to work.

Comment: Actually I've tested this code, unfortunately, it hasn't worked. I tried this one before, but as I said after deleting "next" points to deallocated memory. And tail is used to perform operations like pushBack in a constant time.

Comment: You `delete head` and then use it in `head = head->next`, at which point `head` is an invalid pointer.

Comment: Corrected it. It was supposed to use the local next pointer. Thanks for pointing it out.